# If the father has a UK ban, but the mother is a UK permanent resident, is their child also affected?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I am writing this in relation to my brother. His wife, my sister-in-law, was in UK and my brother was in Ireland. Both were on student visas. So my brother took a risk and went to see her when she was sick.

When my sister-in-law got a work permit they applied for a family visa. In order to make it faster my brother put his signature as his wife's signature. These unfortunate deeds caused a 10 year ban from 2008 until December 2018. Their poor child was only three at that time. Her visa also was refused due to this situation.

So their visa was refused in the category of deception. The reasons given were

1. false signature on wife behalf
2. illegal entry
3. lastly poor account balance

The child is now 10 years old. My question is why the child is refused to rejoin her mother???

After 8 years can they can re-apply? My sister-in-law now has permanent residency and is awaiting Citizenship.

Their family has paid high price for their negligence but is there any ground to re-apply?

Now my brother is in Dubai. Their daughter is in India. My sister-in-law is in Scotland.

I have seen some genuine answers from the gr8 people in this forum. So  I thought I will ask this.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: OP, I tried to make the question and information clearer. Please revert, edit if I've made it incorrect. I think this is question is about the child permanently joining her mother which means it falls under Expatriates (maybe) rather than Travel.

Comment: How did he get caught for illegal entry? Did they catch him in the UK?

Comment: Hi Thapnk you for the reply.When he was here in Ireland in 2008 he tried to go by flight once with student Id I think he caught in Airport straightway

Comment: Thank you Mkennedy for the excellent help.What is Expatriates means??Is it come under any category under legislation??

Comment: Thank you Gayot Fow for ur support in this blog.Your fantastic answers to some of the queries encouraged me to post this question.At the moment we are fighting in the dark'(as you mentioned earlier the vulnerable group) giving money here n there.Do you think that child get any justice?Just becoz of this their entire family is suffering from last 8 yrs.Poor child she is suffering unnecessarily.

Comment: A person needs to be at least 18 before they can be banned.  The ban applies to the father and the father isn't going to be back for a very long time (even when the ban expires). The child can apply any time they want as long as there's an accompanying guardian.

Comment: Thank you Gayot fow for your answer.I noticed in the earlier reply you mentioned about two solicitors Sophie Barrett,Barry O'leary.Can we apply through one those solicitors.Most of the solicitors discouraged my sisterinlaw saying that who will look after your child when you go to wrkC as  she is only wrking at night as a healtbcare wrker..I know there million answers to solve that question.but in the letter it says otherwise

Comment: Those are indicative solicitor names, whether or not they take the case is indeterminate.  I am going to assume this is about reunion and hence  falls under the remit of our sister site, [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).  This site is about tourism and very short-term visas.  Close voting in favour of migration to Expats.

Comment: I would love to send the letters we got from Emmigration to you get real solution. Gayot fow seriously people like you make this world a better place to live.Becoz your knowledge n insights are inspiration to many and for some it is living hope.Bcoz when ur not in your homeland where do you knock for justice??